# Parametro no URL está vindo null

Tags: c#

Tenho uma página que vai chamar uma outra conforme abaixo.

```
if (hdfCdTipoStatus.Value == "2")
    Response.Redirect("/frmANACadastroBens.aspx?/CdProcesso=" +   RetornaProcessoUltimaAnalise(int.Parse(hdfCdUsuario.Value)), false);
```

Acontece que no Load da página `frmANACadastroBens.aspx` eu tento pegar o parâmetro passado pela página chamadora, assim:

```
if (Request["CdProcesso"] != null)
                    {
                        hdfCdProcesso.Value = Request["CdProcesso"];
                    }
```

O que passa que no momento em que eu passo o parâmetro na página chamadora, o parâmetro não está nulo e na página chamada está.
Como eu pego esse parâmetro no momento em que a página está sendo carregada.

Comment: Tenta fazer assim, Response.Redirect("/frmANACadastroBens.aspx?CdProcesso="

Comment: O processo da forma que está quando a página é exibida, aparece. No PageLoad é que eu não estou conseguindo pegar e preciso dele no load

Comment: Fez o redirect deste modo? sem o / antes do ?

Comment: Coloca como resposta para eu fechar o post. Deu certo e nem percebi que havia uma barra. É a pressão dos gestores aqui, rs.

Comment: pronto, já coloquei como resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monte a url do redirect deste modo

```
if (hdfCdTipoStatus.Value == "2")
    Response.Redirect("/frmANACadastroBens.aspx?CdProcesso=" +   RetornaProcessoUltimaAnalise(int.Parse(hdfCdUsuario.Value)), false);
```